# What is the resolution of two horizontally joined pictures?

Tags: resolution

I want to get a confirmation of what the final resolution should be after joining two pictures horizontally.

I have two pictures A and B which have resolutions 100x100 and 100x100, respectively, for the height and width. 
I joined the images.

- Output shows correctly, Image B at the end of the Image A. However, the resolution of join A-B picture is 200x400.
- If I iterate once more for two A-B-s, I get 400x1600.

So each join increases the height resolution and width resolution 2x and 4x, respectively.

This causes problems for me. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: If each image is 100 x 100, output of AB should be 100 x 200. Output of ABAB should be 100 x 400. Am I missing something? Can you post images of what you're specifically talking about?

Comment: How do you join the images?

Answer (score 1):

TimTroiano's answer

> If each image is 100 x 100, output of AB should be 100 x 200. Output
>   of ABAB should be 100 x 400.